# Google sheets script - mass find and replace

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have adapted the script posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48568984/google-sheets-script-find-and-replace-values-from-column#) slightly to suit my needs. It has worked very well for the most part searching through a list of over 4500 records and replacing based on a list of cross references 187 long.

```
  function replMyText(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh1=ss.getSheetByName('summary');
  var sh2=ss.getSheetByName('Dashboard');
  var rgtxt=sh1.getRange('A7:A4934');//text to replace
  var rgrep=sh2.getRange('K2:L188');//replacement table
  var txtA=rgtxt.getValues();
  var repA=rgrep.getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<txtA.length;i++){
    for(var j=0;j<repA.length;j++){
      if(txtA[i][0]==repA[j][0]){
        txtA[i][0]=repA[j][1];
      }
    }
  }
  rgtxt.setValues(txtA);
}
```

There are however 17 items that did not get replaced. The error I see on the script page is "Item already exists". I can't see any difference in those 17 values compared to the ones already replaced. Could anyone provide some guidance as to what the error is referring to ?

Edit: In response to the 1st comment, yes, it would have been handy to have a line number but there was no such thing given. Here is the screen grab of the message-
[image]

...and here is the xref of old item / new item. The list has been shortened as all of the successful replacements have been removed.

[image]

The execution transcript shows as follows -
[image]
[image]

Apologies for not supplying more data up front.

Comment: Surely an error message indicates what line it occurred on? Surely if you want help resolving said issue you would think to indicate said line in your code? And additionally provide execution context, such as the text to be replaced and the replacement? Without any of that, we can't help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the issue is not with the script. The error being returned is actually a "referred" error from the worksheet where the values are being replaced. There was data validation set on that particular column to check for and try to prevent duplicate values from being entered. That was the error message that was being returned. When I suspended the data validation the script completed without error.